# Have a line pass thorough an image with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image, which is the "icon" and a grey line beneath. You can see it on line here http://sundayeventsboutique.it/?lang=en

The markup is quite simple, with bootstrap classes

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row dmbs-header">
            <div class="dmbs-header-img">
                <a href="http://sundayeventsboutique.it/"><img width="300" height="150" alt="Sunday Logo" src="http://sundayeventsboutique.it/wp-content/themes/devdmbootstrap3/img/logo.jpg"></a>
            </div>
    </div>
   </div>
<div class="col-md-8 d-bar">

    <div class="row dmbs-top-menu">

        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">

        </nav>

   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hr-line-grey hr-line-margin"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that i can't seem to be able to move the line above the image, if i use a negative top margin it doesn't move until it goes to the top

[image] while i would like to align it under "sunday events boutique"

Comment: You can't move the actual line element in the HTML?

Comment: I saw it is under "sunday events boutique"

Comment: Everything looks fine on your site.

Comment: I can move the line but i would like it to be right below "sunday events boutique" now it stands below the image. I mean it should be right below "ABOUT" and so on

Answer (score 6):

Add `position:relative` to `.hr-line-grey` and adjust the `top` value

```
.hr-line-grey{
 position:relative;
 top:-63px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.hr-line-grey {
overflow: hidden;
height: 1px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #B5B5B6;
margin: 20px 0px 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 120px;
}
```

Change the class to this.
Also, position:relative will cause responsive issues. 
you should use position:absolute.